# Disabling a link on leftnavigation pane once clicked

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Using Javascript how to disable a link after clicking it once.
The scenario is that:
I have a left navigation pane, having links to distinct JSP's which get displayed in .What I want to accomplish is that after I click a link it should open in the center and the hyperlink should be disabled in the left pane.

I am able to navigate through the left navigation pane. But not able to disable the link of the page which shows up in center.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an hidden span next to the link.

```
<a href="..." id="myLink">your link</a>
<span style="display:none">your alter link text</span>
```

then on the script do

```
$("#myLink").click(function(){ $(this).hide().next().show(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a hidden element and give it a flag value that keeps if the link is disabled or not. Now whenever you click on the link the hidden element will be read by the server and in the second load you can disable your link according to the value of the flag with a simple check in the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
<a onclick="
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){el.onclick=function(){return false;}},1);
" ... >link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#click").click(function(e){
   ...
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that way:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery("a#yourLinkId").click( function(event) {
        jQuery(this).attr('disabled', '');
        // You can optionally prevent default processing and implements your own:
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```